# need help installing NVIDIA 6600gt drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, installation

I have downloaded the drivers from NVIDIA ----NVIDIA-Linux-x86-260.19.36.run----It's for my Nvidia 6600gt APG 8x-- I'm using Ubuntu10.10. How do I get them installed, is there a way that my "additional drivers" program could download it somehow. I have been using Linux for 10 days, so my knowledge is limited. The drivers that are in my "additional drivers" program don't work. Freezes and black screen.

Comment: On Ubuntu 10.10 installing nvidia-current worked ok for my 6600GT card, but why install 10.10 when 11.04 is available with newer drivers ?

Comment: Try installing the recommended driver (the one the "additional drivers" dialog recommends) using the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 1):

I quoted this sentence from NVIDIA linux drivers download page.

**"Note that many Linux distributions provide their own packages of the NVIDIA Linux Graphics Driver in the distribution's native package management format. This may interact better with the rest of your distribution's framework, and you may want to use this rather than NVIDIA's official package."**

How ever these are the steps..

Open a terminal window from Applications ->Accessories menu,and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

then restart you computer,run the command to create the configuration file:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Log out and back in ,and you can now change nvidia settings by System – > Administration -> Nvidia X server Settings

[image]

**Some times after doing these steps also some nvidia cards do not work properly. Some time you may not able to boot in to GUI too. At this time.... use the recovery mode and delete x `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file to get thu GUI back**

Answer (score 0):

Manually installing a driver is not reccommended, especiallyby a new user like you. Since your Card is not a current generation one, You can always use the " 173 " version driver from the "additional drivers" Program. I had a Geforce 6 series card which worked perfectly with 173.12. But if you still want to install manually, here is detailed how-to

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: `nvidia-current` works fine here with a 6600 GT PCIe. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, 173.12 didn't work at all it ran for a minute then closed down  to black screen